# Loop json data into telegram bot

Tags: php, json, telegram-bot

I'm getting a json data to make response in telegram bot when user made a particular text (such as MENU):

```
$menu = file_get_contents('http://www.ilquintoquarto.it/menu.json');
    $obj = json_decode($menu);
        foreach ($obj as $value)
        {
           $response = $value->tipo;
           $response = $response." ".$value->piatto;
        }
```

my problem is that the response dont loop!
If I put the code outside of telegram the loop work fine!

Comment: What makes you think it's not looping? Btw, you just keep overwriting `$response`.

Comment: it show me only the last value of json! Why?

Comment: Because of the second part of my first comment.....

Comment: Ok I understand the problem,  $response = $response." ".$value->tipo; $response = $response." ".$value->piatto; but is possible to format the results?

Answer (score 1):

```
$menu = file_get_contents('http://www.ilquintoquarto.it/menu.json');
$obj = json_decode($menu);
foreach ($obj as $value)
{
   $response[] = $value->tipo." ".$value->piatto;
}
```